# What happens to Google Analytics cookie _ga during 301 redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, cookies, google-analytics

Hi we are migrating our website from `test.com` to `test2.com`. Obviously, I do NOT want returning users to obtain a new Google Analytics `clientId` when being redirected to the new domain.

When doing the `301 redirect`, is Google automatically also transferring the cookie information from `test.com` to `test2.com`? In other words, will `_ga` be the same `cookie`? In case it is not, can I simply override the cookie or how do I do it?

EDIT:
I get the `_ga` information from test.com via `jsonp` request. Hence, I have this information. But which the `_ga` consists of many information such as timestamp, id etc. 
Isn't it possible to override the cookie information of test2.com with the cookie information of test.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are domain specific, so a cookie from test.com will not be valid for test2.com and GA will start a new session. By itself GA will do nothing to mitigate this, especially since a 301 redirect happens before any GA code is executed.

However you could use a serverside script that reads the _ga cookie from test.com, appends it to the redirect url, and set the client id manually on the test2.com (horrible non-production PHP code as example only):

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET('myGAparameter')) {
?>

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto', {
  'clientId': <?php echo $_GET('myGAparameter'); ?>
});

<?php
} else {
?>

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');

<?php
}
?>
```

(This is pretty much the [example from the Google Analytics documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#setting_the_client_id_on_the_destination_domain))

Comment: I see. Thanks for that. I get the _ga information from test.com via jsonp request. Hence, I have this information. But which the _ga consists of many information such as timestamp, id etc. How can I make sure to only send the id itself? Which part of _ga is the id?

Comment: Isn't it possible to override the cookie information of test2.com with the cookie information of test.com

Comment: The ga cookie only contains the client id (this is different from the old version where campaign info etc. also went to the cookie). And if you set the client id manually the Google code will update the cookie for you (but then I assume you do not want the client id to show in the url, is that the problem ?).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get it. But when I look at the _ga cookie information, I get "GA1.1.856210603.1461185750" as cookie. But when I only prompt the clientid it's only the latter part "856210603.1461185750". My question now is if I set the clientId like this ga('set', 'clientId', "GA1.1.856210603.1461185750") or using "856210603.1461185750"??? Hope you can help me this last time. (I do not worry having the id in the url. I built a work around for that).